# Rounding Oracle SYSDATE to the nearest hour

Tags: sql, oracle

Supposing the current SYSDATE is 03-APR-17 03.35.49, my query would need to get values between:

a. SYSDATE rounded to nearest passed hour (in this case 03.00.00)

b. a minus 1 hour = 02.00.00

I have tried and found that using "-1/24" returns the date time with an hour subtracted. Kinda new to Oracle so struggling on the first part.
Not sure if I should be using ROUND or FLOOR or any other functionality.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: "rounded" to the nearest **passed** hour is not called "rounded" at all, it is called "truncated". (Then it will be easy to remember which function to use!)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select sysdate,
       trunc(sysdate, 'hh') as truncated,
       round(sysdate, 'hh') as rounded
from   dual;

SYSDATE              TRUNCATED            ROUNDED
-------------------  -------------------  -------------------
04/03/2017 15:54:22  04/03/2017 15:00:00  04/03/2017 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to truncate the value:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'hh')
from dual;
```

To round it:

```
select trunc(sysdate + interval '30' minute, 'hh')
from dual;
```

Or:

```
select round(sysdate, 'hh')
from dual;
```

I forget that `round()` can also take a format argument.

Answer (score 0):

> my query would need to get values between:
>
> a. SYSDATE rounded to nearest passed hour (in this case 03.00.00)
>
> b. a minus 1 hour = 02.00.00

You can use `TRUNC( date_value, format_mask )` and subtract an `INTERVAL` literal:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'hh24' ) - INTERVAL '1' HOUR
                       AND TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'hh24' );
```